# How can I apply DRY to this JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry, javascript-objects

I have a JavaScript object like this one, which is responsible for managing messages:

```
var _message = {
            removeMessages: function () {
                messageContainer.removeClass(errorClass)
                .removeClass(infoClass)
                .removeClass(successClass)
                .text('');
            },
            info: function (text) {
                this.removeMessages();
                messageContainer.addClass(infoClass).text(text);
            },
            error: function (text) {
                this.removeMessages();
                messageContainer.addClass(errorClass).text(text);
            },
            success: function (text) {
                this.removeMessages();
                messageContainer.addClass(successClass).text(text);
            }
        };
```

Three times the jQuery's `removeClass` has been called. Three times `this.removeMessages();` has been called. Three times I have used `messageContainer.text(text);` to display the text.

Note: messageContainer is a jQuery object and I would use this object as `_message.info('some information');`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove multiple classes at once with [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/):

> **`.removeClass( [className] )`**
>   **classNameOne** or more space-separated classes to be removed from the class attribute of each matched element.

So you could do this:

```
removeMessages: function () {
    messageContainer
        .removeClass(errorClass + ' ' + infoClass + ' ' + successClass)
        .text('');
}
```

You can also clean up the other three with a little helper:

```
_helper: function(text, cls) {
    this.removeMessages();
    messageContainer.addClass(cls).text(text);
},
info: function (text) {
    this._helper(text, infoClass);
},
error: function (text) {
    this._helper(text, errorClass);
},
success: function (text) {
    this._helper(text, successClass);
}
```